# Retrieve emails from Hubspot Workflow API

Tags: hubspot-api

I want to get emails from workflow using Hubspot API.
Those Emails in Hubspot app are identified by an id and a campaign, they're also applied on a specific action in workflow

I tried multiple endpoints and the best seems to request for every workflow with [GET /automation/v3/workflows/:workflowId](https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/workflows/v3/get_workflow).
This request gives me a field nammed "actions" in which I can navigate to retrieve workflow actions and linked emails. Unfortunately it seems that the request only send the first branch of the workflow and I cant retreive emails from other branchs.

Does someone have an idea to get all branches from actions or an other option to get automated emails from workflows ?